# Jquery show more label count?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the label count for div and I am getting count of all labels in that div. Actually  + button will appaer if label count is more than 5 otherwise I am hiding that button using jquery but actually what I want is if label count is more than 5 means button should appear along with count. For example if 6 labels are there means button will appear and also 1 more it should show is what I want please some body help..

```js
 $('#filter-group21').each(function() {
   var label_count = 1;
   label_count = $(this).find('label').length;
   // alert(label_count);
   $(this).find('label:gt(4)').hide();
   // $(this).find('div:gt(5)').hide();
   // display load more if there are more than 5 filters
   $(this).find(".loadMore").toggle(label_count > 5);

 });

 $('.loadMore').click(function() {
   $(this).next().show();
   $(this).parent().find('label').show();
   // $(this).parent().find('div').show();
 });
 // On click of - button need to show only top 5 filter elements
 $('.showLess').click(function() {
   $(this).hide();
   $(this).parent().find('label').not(':lt(5)').hide();
   // $(this).parent().find('div').not(':lt(5)').hide();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filter-group21" class="cf">
  <!--<input type="text" id="dino-search_21" placeholder="Search By FABRIC">  -->
  <label class="checkbox cb_test">
              <input name="filter[]" type="checkbox"  value="144" />
              Chiffon </label>
  <label class="checkbox cb_test">
              <input name="filter[]" type="checkbox"  value="145" />
              Corduroy </label>
  <label class="checkbox cb_test">
              <input name="filter[]" type="checkbox"  value="146" />
              Cotton </label>
  <label class="checkbox cb_test">
              <input name="filter[]" type="checkbox"  value="147" />
              Crepe</label>
  <label class="checkbox cb_test">
              <input name="filter[]" type="checkbox"  value="148" />
              Denim</label>
  <label class="checkbox cb_test">
              <input name="filter[]" type="checkbox"  value="162" />
              Silk</label>
  <button class="loadMore" title="Load more">+</button>
  <button class="showLess" title="Load more">-</button>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$('#filter-group21').each(function() {
  var label_count = 0,
    limit = 5;
  label_count = $(this).find('label').length - limit;
  $(this).find('label:gt(4)').hide();
  if (label_count > 0) {
    $('.loadMore').append(label_count + 'more')
  }
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/r50eLzLv/1/)**

I have added around 8 labels. So it will show +3 more